# Program to check if the scoping is lexical or dynamic

Tags: scope, scheme, racket

I found that the program to check if the scoping is lexical or dynamic is the one given below (source: http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61a/su10/resources/sp11-Jordy/scope/)

```
(define test 
  (let ((scope 'lexical)) 
    (lambda () scope)))

(let ((scope 'dynamic)) 
  (test))
```

But how can this work? This should always print 'lexical (irrespective of whether the scope is lexical or dynamic) right? since in the local scope of the body of the first 'let' , scope is always defined to be 'lexical.. Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 7):

The value of `test` is not

```
(let ((scope 'lexical)) 
    (lambda () scope))
```

it is just

```
(lambda () scope)
```

When you call it, `(test)`, the function body is evaluated, and it consists only of

```
scope
```

With lexical scope, this would be the value in the binding that was in effect when the definition was evaluated, i.e the lexically enclosing `let`-binding.

With dynamic scope, the binding of `scope` isn't looked up until the function is called.
At that time, the binding to `'lexical` is long gone — it only exists during the definition of `test`.

When you

```
(let ((scope 'dynamic)) 
  (test))
```

a new binding is introduced in the environment, and this is the binding that is found when looking up `scope`.

The similar function

```
(define test  
    (lambda () 
        (let ((scope 'whatever))
            scope)))
```

would work the way you suggest — always returning `'whatever` — as the binding to `'whatever` is in effect during the evaluation of `scope` even in a dynamic setting.

Answer (score 6):

Scheme uses lexical scoping, so of course that code always returns `lexical`. However, in a Lisp system that uses dynamic scoping, `scope` would indeed be `dynamic` inside that `(let ((scope 'dynamic)) ...)` expression….

In order to understand that, you have to understand how dynamic scoping is implemented. Think of each variable as having a stack of values.<sup>†</sup> So, when the lambda expression was being evaluated, the value `lexical` has been pushed to `scope`'s value stack (via the `let`). When the `let` block is exited, the value is popped off. Later, the second `let` block pushes the value `dynamic` to `scope`'s value stack, which is what your function then sees.

<sup>†</sup> I highly appreciate [the explanation from the Emacs Lisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dynamic-Binding.html) about how dynamic bindings work in terms of a stack. It's helped me really understand the concept in concrete terms.

Comment: I understood the programs in the link and the stack concept explained here.Thanks for the info. But when the test function is called from the second 'let',the code inside the define block is executed and the let block inside the test function should again push the value 'lexical to the stack before the lambda block is executed, right?... or what is the problem in my understanding of the execution?

Comment: @SubinP The `define` isn't executed when you call the function, the function is already defined to be `(lambda () scope)`.